# UITextView limit text due to number of lines and character count

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uitextview, autolayout

I have a `UITextView`,
which I would like to have two lines maximum.

When the text view has reached two lines and the end of its width, I want it to stop accepting any new characters.

I have tested:

```
UITextView *textView = ...
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
```

This make the text view's UI look correctly but it still accepts new characters and grows the text beyond what is visible in the UI.

Just limiting the number of characters would not be a great idea since every character has its own width and height.

I'm using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the text view's delegate, you can use `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` to return whether text entry should be accepted. Here's a snippet that calculates how tall the new text would be and returns `true` only if the text is less than the maximum characters allows and fits on two lines:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : textView.font};

    CGFloat textWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset));
    textWidth -= 2.0f * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding;
    CGRect boundingRect = [newText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textWidth, 0)
                                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                             attributes:textAttributes
                                                context:nil];

    NSUInteger numberOfLines = CGRectGetHeight(boundingRect) / textView.font.lineHeight;

    return newText.length <= 500 && numberOfLines <= 2;
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear based on the question whether the text should be limited by size AND character count, or just size. If it should be limited by size, remove `newText.length <= 500 &&` from the return statement.

Comment: Only your answer helped me!